Searching for points inside a circle on a sphere surface
I have many points scattered on a sphere surface. I need to find which of them are inside an arbitrary circle drawn on the surface.
This looks like it'd require some sort of space partitioning but I'm not sure what's the best way to partition. My current idea is to do equirectangular un-projection of the points and then use a standard quadtree on them.
Any suggestions for a better approach?

If your points have some kind of valid 'adjacency', you could do like a flood fill to avoid testing all points. E.g points are adjacent iff distance < some constant.

They don't. They're randomly distributed. Not sure if I could establish some adjacency structure for such a set of points.

Maybe just establish a rectangular bounding box containing all the points you need to check. How do you store the points?

What information defines the circle on the sphere? Center as a 3D point and radius/diameter?

It's just a list. Every point is represented by a normal vector determining where it is on the sphere.

The circle is defined as a centerpoint on the sphere surface and a radius measured along the surface of the sphere

For simplicity, it is a unit sphere and all points are expressed as normal vectors.

To be clear, you mean your points are expressed as unit vectors in Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) with x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1?

@Simon, yes, unit vectors in cartesian coordinates. But I can keep them in spherical coordinates as well if needed.

Spherical coordinates might be easier, but tend to be awkward at the poles.

The storage format is not really important as long as it's convertible to cartesian.

@Simon, as for your suggestion to check the bounding box (or other bounding area/volume), that'd still require iterating through all points to determine if they're inside the bounding area.
Imo the question boils down to hierarchical space partitioning to accelerate the search. I'm just not sure what type of partitioning to use for points on a sphere.

By the time you've made use of clever partitioning, or data structures and techniques, you might not be much if any faster than just chugging through all values. I'd look carefully at typical numbers to see if its worth the complexity.

I already profiled the thing. It's a realtime application. Searches are causing bottlenecks so I have to implement some optimization. I forgot to mention that the points are stationary and I need to do many arbitrary searches on the same point set during runtime. So making a partitioning structure at startup should be well worth it in my use case.

One simple idea to reduce the number of points to check would be to sort the list on say latitude. Then you can quickly exclude points outside the latitudes of your circle.

Yes. Not ideal but it can bring the number of visited points down somewhat, depending on circle position and size. Will implement it right away. It's certainly better than nothing.

Use stereographic projection to map the points from the sphere's surface to an infinite plane. Then construct an ordinary Delaunay Triangulation on these points, before mapping the edges back to the original points on your sphere surface. You'll now have a Delaunay Triangulation of the sphere surface points.
Now insert your points into a standard KD-tree or other 3D+ space partitioning data structure, and query for the nearest point to the center of your circle on the surface. From that point, run a breadth-first search on the graph constructed earlier and test if each point falls within your circle as already explained in the other answers / comments. Only expand the frontier from nodes within the circle.

I'm just not sure how to handle sphere wrapping when doing triangulation.

@nj16 Here's an article that explains the process in greater detail and shares code for it: https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1842-delaunay-voronoi-sphere/

Given the center and radius of the circle and imagining it as a cone with its apex at the center of the sphere, you can use the dot product to determine which points are inside the cone and which are not.
As you can see here, the dot product of two vectors is equal to the cosine of the angle between them, if both are unit vectors.
Given:

O the center of the sphere
C the center of the circle
R any point along the circle
T the point to test
V = normalized(OC)
refCos = V · normalized(OR)

The points inside the circle will be those that have a dot product greater than or equal to refCos:
testCos = V · normalized(OT)
isInside = testCos >= refCos

This is an image from Wikipedia spherical circle to make it easier for you to view:

If you can calculate the bounding box of the circle, in the broad phase you can verify that the points to test are inside the box. If I'm not mistaken, using the points in the four quadrants of the circle you should have a correct bounding box.
Or you can use another partitioning algorithm.
EDIT:

For simplicity, it is a unit sphere and all points are expressed as normal vectors.

Using normal vectors there is no need to calculate their magnitude (which involves calculating their length via square root), and the dot product simplifies to simple multiplications which are very fast.

Sorry if I don't use mathematical notation but I don't know how to specify it in markdown.

The strictly geometric part is trivial. The question is really about searching. The point set is constant but I need to do many searches on it with arbitrary circles. What you're suggesting doesn't in any way eliminate brute force iteration over all points for every search.

The dot product calculation might be faster than what you're doing if you're calculating square roots at all. You want it to be fast right. Maybe checking all points but faster is worth considering. I'm just speculating about how it is done currently. Why not share the details and ask for suggestions on how to make it faster.

It's obviously done via dot product. How else would you reasonably check? The point set is large and doing frequent linear searches on the whole set is not fast enough. It's a realtime application and it's causing bottlenecks. The only way I see it done bruteforce is by using a compute shader, but I'd much rather have an algorithmic/partitioning solution.

Your circle is defined by

its C(Xc, Yc) center
its r radius

Any P(Xp, Yp) is ** strictly inside** the circle if
d(C, P) < r
Any P(Xp, Yp) is on the border of the circle if
d(C, P) = r
Any P(Xp, Yp) is outside of the circle if
d(C, P) > r
where d is the distance and can be computed as
d(C, P) = sqrt(sqr(Xc - Xp) + sqr(Yc - Yp))
finally, P(Xp, Yp) is not outside the circle if
d(C, P) <= r
Hence, if you know the center of your circle as well as its radius as well as the point you want to check, then just use the theorem above.
If you have multiple points and multiple circles, then:
for each P of Points
    inside <- false
    for each C of Circles
        inside <- inside OR d(C, P) < r(C)
    end for
    //do whatever you want with inside
end for

Of course you can optimize the algorithm above so when you find the first circle the point is inside, you avoid checking for further circles of that point.
EDIT
Sure-enough in some cases you can optimize the search if there are large(!) spaces where circles are not to be found. You could check for your points whether they happen at those spaces and exclude those which are from your consequent search inside circles.
If you know nothing about the circles and points beforehand, then I would say that such spaces need to be at least twice the size of your circles to even consider them to be "large". If you have additional information, like the probability of your points or circles to be at a certain location, then you can use that extra information to boost your algorithm.
However, pre-analysing the problem-space in this manner is by itself a slow process and may be unfeasible to do, unless you can reuse the results (for example you scatter points 1000 times but the circles remain at the same places).
So analyze your problem-space, find out whether there is indeed a performance issue to be fixed and if so, then proceed with fixing the issues, but identifying regions where circles are not to be found.

The question is not about determining if a point is inside a circle. That's trivial. It's about how to search to avoid brute force checking of all points.

@nj16 edited my answer addressing the issues you mentioned.

It's a realtime application and this search is causing bottlenecks. The points are stationary and many searches are typically needed during runtime. So doing preprocessing is totally warranted. The real question is, how to preprocess to best accelerate the searches. I already mentioned above that some sort of hierarchical partitioning is likely the way to go. I have experience in implementing quad and oc trees for space partitioning. This is however a bit of a special case as the space that is partitioned is 2D, but wrapped around a sphere. Hence my initial idea of using euirect projection
